# 3d Surface plot from linear model with matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, linearmodels

The following code was working fine. But now it is throwing the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
from matplotlib import cm

csv = pd.read_csv('http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv', index_col=0)
print(csv)
model = sm.ols(formula='sales ~ TV + radio', data = csv)
fit = model.fit()

fit.summary()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x_surf = np.arange(0, 350, 20)                # generate a mesh
y_surf = np.arange(0, 60, 4)
x_surf, y_surf = np.meshgrid(x_surf, y_surf)

exog = pd.core.frame.DataFrame({'TV': x_surf.ravel(), 'radio': y_surf.ravel()})
out = fit.predict(exog = exog)
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf,
                out.reshape(x_surf.shape),
                rstride=1,
                cstride=1,
                color='None',
                alpha = 0.4)

ax.scatter(csv['TV'], csv['radio'], csv['sales'],
           c='blue',
           marker='o',
           alpha=1)

ax.set_xlabel('TV')
ax.set_ylabel('Radio')
ax.set_zlabel('Sales')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the reshape function on the "values" attribute of the "out" Series object:

```
out = fit.predict(exog = exog)
ax.plot_surface(x_surf, y_surf,
                out.values.reshape(x_surf.shape),
                rstride=1,
                cstride=1,
                color='None',
                alpha = 0.4)
```